# Loading all PPI information from Uniprot into a graph in NetworkX

Tags: python, uniprot

I am looking for guidance to load all SwissProt PPI data for Homo sapiens into a graph (from NetworkX). In particular, the part that I'm struggling with is gathering the data from SwissProt for each human protein.

---

The data that I'm looking to extract is protein-protein interaction. This is not included in the files found [here](ftp://ftp.uniprot.org/pub/databases/uniprot/current_release/knowledgebase/idmapping/by_organism/), which @rtviii (answer below) suggested to use. Rather, when say you click on an entry in SwissProt, for each entry, there is a section devoted to "Interaction" as shown in the image attached below. I would like to extract that information for each human protein, and load it into a graph data structure using NetworkX

[image]

---

EDIT 2:

How I ended up doing it:

```
    query = "reviewed:yes+AND+organism:9606"
    args = {'query': query, 'format': 'xls', 'columns':'id,entry name,interactor'}

    uniprot_url = "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?{}".format(urllib.parse.urlencode(args))

    with open(<DESIRED FILE PATH>, "wb") as target:
          target.write(requests.get(url).content)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Are you starting with a list of proteins and want to find their interactions? If so, why not go straight to Mint or Intact (but be careful with Intact, there's a lot of dirty data in there)? Why would you start from uniprot? If you want to build a high quality human PPI network, this really isn't the simplest or best approach. You might want to ask a new question, taking a step back to basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query link for all interactors would be thus : `https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=organism%3A9606+AND+interactor%3A*&sort=score`

---

There is always an option of downloading the static version of the service if you find it incovnient to deal with their API for your use case [from here](ftp://ftp.uniprot.org/pub/databases/uniprot/) and have it all to yourself, pipe data into your dataframes locally. I find it useful to just broswe their repositories sometimes instead of reading the specifications.

In general, you can get a variety of datashapes  from uniprot that you cannot get from their static database-image by specifying the appropriate parameters in the request. You can browse and explore parameters by expanding their GUI's **search fields** as described in [this little guide](http://insideuniprot.blogspot.com/2015_03_01_archive.html). Then you can request your data like so, in python for example.

```
import requests
URL = "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"
PARAMS = {'organism': 9606, 'format': 'tab', ....#Additional parameters#...}
response = requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I was already able to download the database data, I'll explain in more detail what it is exactly that I need in the post.

Comment: @AnIgnorantWanderer Added query for interactors. Tag on ```&format=tab``` to make your life easier once you get to python.